# Como transformar uma imagem em um qr code com Zxing?

Tags: java, android, qrcode

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo android capaz de gerar e ler qr codes, a aplicação já encodifica e decodifica strings, mas agora preciso fazer isso com imagens.

Já tentei alguns caminhos como transformar a imagem em um array de bytes e em seguida transformá-la em string no formato Base64, porém a stirng fica muito longa.

Já tentei diminuir o tamanho da imagem para, consequentemente, diminuir o tamanho da string, porém, a imagem fica muito pequena, até aqui só consegui depois que diminui o tamanho da imagem para menos de 2KB mas ela fica muito pequena e sem qualidade.

Existe alguma forma de transformar uma imagem em um qrcode utilizando a library zxing?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Fazer o upload da imagem em algum lugar e usar o QR Code da URL não é uma opção para você?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No link abaixo, descobri que um qr code não pode conter muito mais do que 1000KB e uma imagem deste tamanho seria muito pequena e inviável para meu propósito.

http://qrdroid.com/blog/encode-any-image-as-a-qr-code/